# Installing Nvidia Geforce on Ubuntu 14.10 & 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, 14.10

I installed Nvidia Geforce GTX 850m driver from Nvidia official site on Ubuntu 14.10 & 14.04 and when restart laptop after installation process I get black screen I can't even access terminal 
I don't know what's wrong with this driver ?

Any way to install the driver and work fine ?

Comment: Unless you need a newer version (340 vs. 331), I'd recommend using Driver Manager (bottom row of the System Settings utility) to handle your video driver install/updates -- that way you get automatic updates from the repositories and better odds of a reliable driver than using the "latest" direct from nVidia.  Won't help you for getting into Ubuntu with your black screen, though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If u get only black screen than try it.first start your ubuntu in nomodoset
here is solution open this link and follow step

[My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

here is simple step:-

when the grub menu appear press 'e' to edit button

then find *quiet splash* and delete this quiet splash

and type nomodeset  and than press ctrl+x

you can install your graphics driver

but remeber your screen resoultion set 800x600

but dnt worry after your system reboot u can access your ubuntu in 800x600 resolution...

open your terminal and type

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
sudo add-age-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get-update
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia linux-headers-generic